# How can I change the grouping when displaying data from two joined tables?

Tags: php, mysql

I have joined two tables, customers and orders, on the customer id value.
There are multiple entries in orders table with same customer id.

When I display the entries of orders table, each order is followed by the customer details.
Instead, I want the customer details to be displayed *once* followed by all the orders with that customer's id.

How do I do that using PHP and MySQL?

I want the output to be like

```
Customer1_name 
Item 1  Quantity
Item 2  Quantity

Customer2_name
Item1  Quantity
Item2  Quantity
```

But what I'm getting is

```
Customer1_name 
item1 quantity
Customer1_name 
item2 quantity
```

if he has ordered 2 items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, like this:

Execute your query, ordering first by customer ID, then by order ID, (or whatever you want to sort your orders by within each customer section). It is important to `ORDER BY customer_id` *first*; if you do not, this method will not work.

```
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM customers 
    INNER JOIN orders ON customers.id = orders.customer_id ORDER BY customer_id, order_id');
```

As you fetch the results, keep track of the customer, and when it changes, output the new customer information and replace the current customer with the new customer.

```
$customer_id = null;                          // current customer - initialize to null
while ($row = $stmt->fetchObject()) {
    if ($row->customer_id != $customer_id) {
        // customer is different, so start a new customer section
        echo $row->customer_name;
        $customer_id = $row->customer_id;    // reset the current customer
    }
    // always output your order information regardless of whether the customer has changed
    echo $row->order_info;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach can be achieved using `GROUP_CONCAT()` function, you will get customer details only once, and other order details in separate column separated by comma.

Considering Your table structure I wrote following query, change the column names as per your requirement.

```
SELECT a.customer_id, a.cust_name, GROUP_CONCAT(b.item_name) FROM customers a 
INNER JOIN orders b ON a.customer_id = b.customer_id
GROUP BY a.customer_id
```

Comment: Yeah! this way you get entire result from MySQL only. Later you can display the output in the php as per your needs.